# Print Error in Console and both Error & Output in Log file - UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script with two run time arguments. During the execution if i get any error, then it needs to redirected to a error file and in console. Also both error and output needs to be redirected to a log file.

Currently the error output is getting copied to err file and getting displayed in console too. 
But in log file the output and error message it getting redirected twice.

`Code`

```
#! /bin/sh    
errExit ()
{
    errMsg=`cat $1.log >> "$1".err`
    cat "$1".err | tee /dev/fd/3    
   return
}

test()
{
logfile=$1
exec 3>&1 1>>"${logfile}".log 2>&1
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo " "
echo "#################################################"
echo "Hi Hello,This is first function"
echo "#################################################"
if [[ -z "$2" ]];
then 
errExit $logfile
return
else
#<some Commands Here>
fi
}

test_1()
{
logfile=$1
exec 3>&1 1>>"${logfile}".log 2>&1
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo " "
echo "#################################################"
echo "Hi Hello,This is second function"
echo "#################################################"
if [[ -z "$2" ]];
then 
errExit $logfile
return
else
#<some Commands Here>
fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the purpose of some parts of your script, nor exactly what you want logged and why, but I'll take a quick swing.

**Your Current Logging**

The current logging is a bit circuitous. 3 points to console, while 2 points to 1 after 1 is redirected into your logfile. In the case of an error, you copy the entire log into an error file, then post the entire error file using tee. By design, tee prints to 1 (not console) and whatever file you specify, so when you post the error file, which is the entire log, to 1 and to 3, it prints it in the console (3), but also adds the entire log to the log. Essentially you've moved things around so tee no longer works as expected and becomes irrelevant. Also, since you're using exec to change the pipes, these changes will last for your entire script, possibly interfering with output.

**My Recommendation**

I would suggest that you preserve the function of the output streams to avoid confusion. You can remove the logging from your functions entirely by adding it to the function call. So if your function call used to be `test log_filename other_arg`, you could change it to `test other_arg | tee log_filename.log`. This would post everything to the terminal, but stdout also gets logged. You'd probably prefer

```
LOG=log_filename
test other_arg 2>&1 | tee "${LOG}.log"
```

so that the log includes stderr. This would also allow your errExit function to only need to be this:

```
errExit ()
{
    errMsg=`cp "${LOG}.log" "${LOG}.err"` # No useless cat calls ;)
    return
}
```

As a side benefit, because the `2>&1` redirect is in the function call, the rest of the script output would revert to normal behavior. Although I didn't post it, you would need to modify your functions to no longer expect or handle the logfile as the first argument.

**The Simplest Fix**

If you literally just want to fix your code with the least refactoring, or didn't want things always printing to console, just change the second line of the errExit function from `cat "$1".err | tee /dev/fd/3` to `cat "$1".err >&3`

**I can tailor the answer to suit your logging needs if you comment with feedback :)**

Comment: I have tried the above approach but it didnt worked out

Comment: Can you clarify which part of my approach you tried and what didn't work? I have used this method in a few scripts, so if it truly isn't working, there may be some other issue.